# How to print certain columns by name?

Tags: awk

I have the following file:

```
id  name  age
1   ed    50
2   joe   70
```

I want to print just the `id` and `age` columns. Right now I just use `awk`:

```
cat file.tsv | awk '{ print $1, $3 }'
```

However, this requires knowing the column numbers. Is there a way to do it where I can use the name of the column (specified on the first row), instead of the column number?

Comment: If not *column number*, then **what** would you like to depend on?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz The name; he wants to say `id` instead of `$1` and `age` instead of `$3`

Comment: see also discussion on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846300/print-column-name-that-matches-string-from-commandline)

Comment: Okay, "column names" not "column numbers". But what if your first (header) row  contains duplicates?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$ cat t.awk
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        ix[$i] = i
    }
}
NR>1 {
    print $ix[c1], $ix[c2]
}
$ awk -f t.awk c1=id c2=name input 
1 ed
2 joe
$ awk -f t.awk c1=age c2=name input 
50 ed
70 joe
```

If you want to specify the columns to print on the command line, you could do something like this:

```
$ cat t.awk 
BEGIN {
    split(cols,out,",")
}
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        ix[$i] = i
}
NR>1 {
    for(i=1; i <= length(out); i++)
        printf "%s%s", $ix[out[i]], OFS
    print ""
}
$ awk -f t.awk -v cols=name,age,id,name,id input 
ed 1 ed 50 1 
joe 2 joe 70 2
```

(Note the `-v` switch to get the variable defined in the `BEGIN` block.)

Comment: The 2nd example does not output the columns in the expected order, `for (i in out)` has no inherent ordering. `gawk` offers `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` as a solution, iterating over the index with a `for( ; ; )` is probably better.

Comment: @BrettThomas, highly recommend [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).  (If you have access to lynda.com, I even more highly recommend "Awk Essential Training," which covers all the same material but more concisely and with practice exercises.)

Comment: Mr. Spuratic, you da man.  I ran across the for( i in out) problem, worked fine w/ 3 fields, when I added 2 it did 4,5,1,2,3, instead of 1,2,3,4,5 like I was expecting.  To get them in order you have to do for(i=1; i <= length(out); i++)

Comment: This is by far still the best answer I found at the end of 2022, other solutions are not as elegant and convenient.
I want to improve on it by mentioning that if your input has any other delimiter (not spaces or tabs), you will get an extra field in the output because of the `OFS` printing. Also, a more elegant and direct way of getting the `out` length is from the `split`: `len=split(cols,out,","`. Now the 2nd `for` loop becomes (also resolves extra field printing): `for(i=1; i<=len; i++) {if(i<len) printf "%s%s", $ix[out[i]], OFS}; if(i=len) print $ix[out[i]]}` (can't write code block here)

Comment: @one-liner first `awk` answer gives no warning if duplicate column names are present, and returns duplicate copies of the _first_-named column it encounters, instead of moving on to output an _identically_-named second column.

Answer (score 12):

### [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io)

Convert the input data to a csv format and use a csv tool such as [`csvcut`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvcut.html) from the `csvkit`:

```
$ cat test-cols.dat 
id  name  age
1   ed    50
2   joe   70
```

Install csvkit:

```
$ pip install csvkit
```

Use `tr` with its squeeze option `-s` to convert it into a valid csv file and apply `csvcut`:

```
$ cat test-cols.dat | tr -s ' ' ',' | csvcut -c id,age
id,age
1,50
2,70
```

If you want to return to the old data format, you can use `tr ',' ' ' | column -t`

```
$ cat test-cols.dat | tr -s ' ' ',' | csvcut -c id,age | tr ',' ' ' | column -t
id  age
1   50
2   70
```

**Notes**

- csvkit supports also different delimiters ([shared option](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_arguments.html) `-d` or `--delimiter`), but returns a csv file:

  - If the file uses only spaces to separate columns (no tabs at all), following works

    ```
    $ csvcut -d ' ' -S -c 'id,age' test-cols.dat
    id,age
    1,50
    2,70
    ```
  - If the file uses a tab to separate columns, following works and [`csvformat`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvformat.html) can be used to get back tsv file:

    ```
    $ csvcut -t -c 'id,age' test-cols.dat | csvformat -T
    id  age
    1   50
    2   70
    ```

    As far as I  have checked, only a single tab is allowed.
- [`csvlook`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvlook.html) can format the table in a markdown table format

  ```
  $ csvcut -t -c "id,age" test-cols.dat | csvlook
  | id | age |
  | -- | --- |
  |  1 |  50 |
  |  2 |  70 |
  ```
- [UUOC (Useless Use Of Cat)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#UUOC_(Useless_Use_Of_Cat)): I like it this way to construct the command.

Comment: +1. But unnecessary uses of `tr`, too.  TSV files are supported directly, without any need to convert them to CSV. The `-t` (aka `--tabs`) option tells `cvscut` to use tabs as field delimiter.  And `-d` or `--delimiter` to use any character as delimiter.

Comment: With some testing, it seems the `-d` and `-t` options are semi-broken.  they work to specify the input delimiter, but the output delimiter is hardcoded to always be a comma.  IMO that's broken - it should either be the same as the input delimiter or have another option to allow the user to set the output delimiter, like `awk`'s FS and OFS vars.

Answer (score 5):

Just trowing a Perl solution into the lot:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wnla

BEGIN {
    @f = ('id', 'age');   # field names to print
    print "@f";           # print field names
}

if ($. == 1) {            # if line number 1
    @n = @F;              #   get all field names
} else {                  # or else
    @v{@n} = @F;          #   map field names to values
    print "@v{@f}";       #   print values based on names
}
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>If you just want to refer to those fields by their *names* instead of numbers, you can use `read`:</strike>

```
while read id name age
do
  echo "$id $age"
done < file.tsv
```

#### EDIT

I saw your meaning at last! Here's a bash function that will print out only the columns you specify on the command line (by *name*).

```
printColumns () 
{ 
read names
while read $names; do
    for col in $*
    do
        eval "printf '%s ' \$$col"
    done
    echo
done
}
```

Here's how you can use it with the file you've presented:

```
$ < file.tsv printColumns id name
1 ed 
2 joe
```

(The function reads `stdin`. `< file.tsv printColumns ...`  is equivalent of `printColumns ... < file.tsv` and `cat file.tsv | printColumns ...`)

```
$ < file.tsv printColumns name age
ed 50 
joe 70 

$ < file.tsv printColumns name age id name name name
ed 50 1 ed ed ed 
joe 70 2 joe joe joe
```

*Note: Pay attention to the names of the columns you request! This version lacks sanity checks, so nasty things can happen if one of the arguments is something like `"anything; rm /my/precious/file"`*

Comment: This is nice, thanks. I'm working with large files (1000 columns, millions of rows) so am using awk for speed.

Comment: @BrettThomas Oh I see. I'm very curious then: could you post some benchmark that gives the time comparison? (Use `time { command(s); }`).

Comment: @rozceitrewaicz: `time cat temp.txt | ./col1 CHR POS > /dev/null 
99.144u 38.966s 2:19.27 99.1% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
time awk -f col2 c1=CHR c2=POS temp.txt > /dev/null
0.294u 0.127s 0:00.50 82.0% 0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w`

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth. This can handle any number of columns in the source, and any number of columns to print, in whatever output sequence you choose; just re-arrange the args...

eg. call: `script-name id age`

```
outseq=($@)
colnum=($( 
  for ((i; i<${#outseq[@]}; i++)) ;do 
    head -n 1 file |
     sed -r 's/ +/\n/g' |
      sed -nr "/^${outseq[$i]}$/="
  done ))
tr ' ' '\t' <<<"${outseq[@]}"
sed -nr '1!{s/ +/\t/gp}' file |
  cut -f $(tr ' ' ','<<<"${colnum[@]}")
```

output

```
id      age
1       50
2       70
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one quick way for selecting a single column.

Say we want the column named "foo":

```
f=file.csv; colnum=`head -1 ${f} | sed 's/,/\n/g' | nl | grep 'foo$' | cut -f 1 `; cut -d, -f ${colnum} ${f}
```

Basically, take the header line, split it into multiple lines with one column name per line, number the lines, select the line with the desired name, and retrieve the associated line number; then use that line number as the column number to the cut command.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is easier just to look at the file header, count the number of the column you need (*c*) and then use Unix `cut`:

```
cut -f c -d, file.csv
```

But when there are many columns or many files I use the following ugly trick:

```
cut \
  -f $(head -1 file.csv | sed 's/,/\'$'\n/g' | grep -n 'column name' | cut -f1 -d,) \
  -d, \ 
  file.csv
```

Tested on OSX, the `file.csv` is comma-delimted.

Answer (score 2):

If the file you're reading *could never possibly* be user-generated, you could abuse the read builtin:

```
f=file.tsv
read $(head -n1 "$f") extra <<<`seq 100`
awk "{print \$$id, \$$age}" "$f"
```

The input file's entire first line is substituted into the argument list, so `read` is passed all the field names from the header line as variable names. The first of these gets assigned the 1 that `seq 100` generates, the second gets the 2, the third gets the 3 and so on. Excess `seq` output is soaked up by the dummy variable `extra`. If you know the number of input columns ahead of time, you can change the 100 to match and get rid of `extra`.

The `awk` script is a double-quoted string, allowing the shell variables defined by `read` to be substituted into the script as `awk` field numbers.

Answer (score 2):

`awk`, for all its vintage, is inherently integer-indexed, as is `cut`.

Here are several tools designed to handle name-indexed data (most of them handling just CSV and TSV, which are very popular file formats):

- https://github.com/shenwei356/csvtk
- http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/540/
- https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv
- https://github.com/johnkerl/miller
- https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils-dlang

Comment: A generous list, thank you. Unfortunately no discussion on this page about handling duplicate "column" names. Reject as an error? Handle and return in same order (column number order)? How do your `github.com` links fare?

Answer (score 1):

Try this small awk utility to cut specific headers - https://github.com/rohitprajapati/toyeca-cutter

Example usage -

```
awk -f toyeca-cutter.awk -v c="col1, col2, col3, col4" my_file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

See below command-

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "id" ){a=i} else if($i == "age"){b=i}} 
    {print $a, $b}' file.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a similar solution (I need the column named id, which might have a varying column number), I came across this one:

```
head -n 1 file.csv | awk -F',' ' {
      for(i=1;i < NF;i++) {
         if($i ~ /id/) { print i }
      }
} '
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Python script for this purpose that basically works like this:

```python3
with fileinput.input(args.file) as data:
    headers = data.readline().split()
    selectors = [any(string in header for string in args.fixed_strings) or
                 any(re.search(pat, header) for pat in args.python_regexp)
                 for header in headers]

    print(*itertools.compress(headers, selectors))
    for line in data:
        print(*itertools.compress(line.split(), selectors))
```

I called it `hgrep` for *header grep*, it can be used like this:

```bash
$ hgrep data.txt -F foo bar -P ^baz$
$ hgrep -F foo bar -P ^baz$ -- data.txt
$ grep -v spam data.txt | hgrep -F foo bar -P ^baz$
```

The whole script is a bit longer, because it uses `argparse` to parse command line arguments and the code is as follows:

```python3
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import fileinput
import itertools
import re
import sys
import textwrap


def underline(s):
    return '\033[4m{}\033[0m'.format(s)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    usage='%(prog)s [OPTIONS] {} [FILE]'.format(
        underline('column-specification')),
    description=
        'Print selected columns by specifying patterns to match the headers.',
    epilog=textwrap.dedent('''\
    examples:
      $ %(prog)s data.txt -F foo bar -P ^baz$
      $ %(prog)s -F foo bar -P ^baz$ -- data.txt
      $ grep -v spam data.txt | %(prog)s -F foo bar -P ^baz$
    '''),
    formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
)

parser.add_argument(
    '-d', '--debug', action='store_true', help='include debugging information')
parser.add_argument(
    'file', metavar='FILE', nargs='?', default='-',
    help="use %(metavar)s as input, default is '-' for standard input")
spec = parser.add_argument_group(
    'column specification', 'one of these or both must be provided:')
spec.add_argument(
    '-F', '--fixed-strings', metavar='STRING', nargs='*', default=[],
    help='show columns containing %(metavar)s in header\n\n')
spec.add_argument(
    '-P', '--python-regexp', metavar='PATTERN', nargs='*', default=[],
    help='show a column if its header matches any %(metavar)s')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.debug:
    for k, v in sorted(vars(args).items()):
        print('{}: debug: {:>15}: {}'.format(parser.prog, k, v),
              file=sys.stderr)

if not args.fixed_strings and not args.python_regexp:
    parser.error('no column specifications given')


try:
    with fileinput.input(args.file) as data:
        headers = data.readline().split()
        selectors = [any(string in header for string in args.fixed_strings) or
                     any(re.search(pat, header) for pat in args.python_regexp)
                     for header in headers]

        print(*itertools.compress(headers, selectors))
        for line in data:
            print(*itertools.compress(line.split(), selectors))

except BrokenPipeError:
    sys.exit(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print()
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the solution from srk (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115226/79404) a little bit more universal.

**Note:** my answer doesn't work for the initially mentioned case with space as a separator. Please let me know if have ideas how to fix it.

Put this into `.bashrc`:

```
printcol() {
  FILE="$1"
  COLUMN="$2"
  SEPARATOR="${3:-|}" # You can change default separator here.
  cut -f $(head -1 "$FILE" | \
    # Remove BOM characters
    sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' | \
    # Print each column name on a separate line
    sed 's/'$SEPARATOR'/\'$'\n/g' | \
    grep -P -n '^'$COLUMN'$' | \
    cut -f1 -d":") -d $SEPARATOR "$FILE"
}
```

Usage for the file with `|` separator:

```
printcol my_file.csv ColumnName
```

Usage for the file with `,` separator:

```
printcol my_file.csv ColumnName ","
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mo=$(awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /name|age/){print i}}}' filename|awk 'ORS=" "')
col1=`echo $mo| awk '{print $1}'`
col2=`echo $mo| awk '{print $2}'`
awk -v col1="$col1" -v col2="$col2" '{print $col1,$col2}' filename


name age
ed 50
joe 70
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this awk function which prints the columns in the specified order (and not in the original order like how `cut -f3,1` is the same as `cut -f1,3`):

`tcut(){ awk -F\\t 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}FNR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)b[$i]=i}{for(i in a)printf"%s"(i==length(a)?RS:FS),$(b[a[i]])}' <(printf %s\\n "$@") -;};tcut id age<file.tsv`

Another option:

```
csvtk -t cut -f id,age file.tsv
```

The `-t` flag uses tab as field separator but it doesn't disable CSV-style treatment of double quotes. The `-l` flag (`--lazy-quotes`) allows including unescaped double quotes as part of the data, but it still prints pairs of double quotes around fields that contain double quotes, so for example the field `aa"aa` is changed to `""aa"aa""`. `-l` also doesn't disable removing double quotes around fields that don't need to be quoted in CSV, so for example the field `"bb"` is changed to `bb`.