# Is there a command line spell to save specific columns by name in a CSV-file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files, csv

Suppose I have a crazy data set in CSV:

```
SOS_VOTERID,COUNTY_NUMBER,COUNTY_ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,SUFFIX,DATE_OF_BIRTH,REGISTRATION_DATE,PARTY_AFFILIATION,RESIDENTIAL_ADDRESS1,RESIDENTIAL_SECONDARY_ADDR,city,RESIDENTIAL_STATE,zip,RESIDENTIAL_ZIP_PLUS4,RESIDENTIAL_COUNTRY,RESIDENTIAL_POSTALCODE,MAILING_ADDRESS1,MAILING_SECONDARY_ADDRESS,MAILING_CITY,MAILING_STATE,MAILING_ZIP,MAILING_ZIP_PLUS4,MAILING_COUNTRY,MAILING_POSTAL_CODE,CAREER_CENTER,CITY,CITY_SCHOOL_DISTRICT,COUNTY_COURT_DISTRICT,CONGRESSIONAL_DISTRICT,COURT_OF_APPEALS,EDUCATIONAL_SERVICE_CENTER_DISTRICT,EXEMPTED_VILLAGE_SCHOOL_DISTRICT,LIBRARY,LOCAL_SCHOOL_DISTRICT,MUNICIPAL_COURT_DISTRICT,PRECINCT_NAME,PRECINCT_CODE,STATE_BOARD_OF_EDUCATION,STATE_REPRESENTATIVE_DISTRICT,STATE_SENATE_DISTRICT,TOWNSHIP,VILLAGE,WARD,PRIMARY-03/07/2000,GENERAL-11/07/2000,SPECIAL-05/08/2001,GENERAL-11/06/2001,PRIMARY-05/07/2002,GENERAL-11/05/2002,SPECIAL-05/06/2003,GENERAL-11/04/2003,PRIMARY-03/02/2004,GENERAL-11/02/2004,SPECIAL-02/08/2005,PRIMARY-05/03/2005,PRIMARY-09/13/2005,GENERAL-11/08/2005,SPECIAL-02/07/2006,PRIMARY-05/02/2006,GENERAL-11/07/2006,PRIMARY-05/08/2007,PRIMARY-09/11/2007,GENERAL-11/06/2007,PRIMARY-11/06/2007,GENERAL-12/11/2007,PRIMARY-03/04/2008,PRIMARY-10/14/2008,GENERAL-11/04/2008,GENERAL-11/18/2008,PRIMARY-05/05/2009,PRIMARY-09/08/2009,PRIMARY-09/15/2009,PRIMARY-09/29/2009,GENERAL-11/03/2009,PRIMARY-05/04/2010,PRIMARY-07/13/2010,PRIMARY-09/07/2010,GENERAL-11/02/2010,PRIMARY-05/03/2011,PRIMARY-09/13/2011,GENERAL-11/08/2011,PRIMARY-03/06/2012,GENERAL-11/06/2012,PRIMARY-05/07/2013,PRIMARY-09/10/2013,PRIMARY-10/01/2013,GENERAL-11/05/2013,PRIMARY-05/06/2014,GENERAL-11/04/2014,PRIMARY-05/05/2015
OH0012781511,87,26953,HOUSEHOLDER,SHERRY,LEIGH,,11/26/1965,08/19/1988,,211 N GARFIELD ST ,   ,BLOOMDALE,OH,44817,,,,  PO BOX 222  ,   ,BLOOMDALE,OH,44817,,,,PENTA JVSD,,,,05,06,WOOD EDUC SRV CTR,,,ELMWOOD LOCAL SD,BOWLING-GREEN,BLOOM TWP BLOOMDALE,87-P-ABO,02,03,02,,BLOOMDALE VILLAGE,,D,,,X,,X,,,,X,,,,,,,,,,,,,D,,X,,,,,,X,,,,,,,,,X,,,,,,,
OH0012781528,87,31122,KEATON,JENNIFER,KAI,,11/27/1968,07/13/2015,,110 N GARFIELD ST ,   ,BLOOMDALE,OH,44817,,,,  PO BOX 16  ,   ,BLOOMDALE,OH,44817,,,,PENTA JVSD,,,,05,06,WOOD EDUC SRV CTR,,,ELMWOOD LOCAL SD,BOWLING-GREEN,BLOOM TWP BLOOMDALE,87-P-ABO,02,03,02,,BLOOMDALE VILLAGE,,,X,,,,,,,,X,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,X,,,,,,X,,,,,,,X,,X,,,,,,,
```

And I wish only to save the city and zip columns; Is there a simple command line spell, that I can specify the two names as arguments and save only those two columns in a new CSV file?

Comment: Here's a similar question (minus the comma separators) [How to print certain columns by name?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/how-to-print-certain-columns-by-name). Another recipe using `awk` here: [Using Field Names to Reference Columns](http://awk.info/?doc/tip/readheaders.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you have simple, comma-separated columns, you can do it with awk. Parse the first line to determine the columns you want, and then print those columns.

```
wanted_columns=city,zip
wanted_columns=",$wanted_columns," awk -F, '
    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if (index(ENVIRON["wanted_columns"], ","$i",")) {last=i; columns[i]=","}
            columns[last]="\n"
        }
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if (columns[i]) printf "%s%s", $i, columns[i]
        }
    }'
```

Alternatively, you can use `cut`; this will be faster if the file is large. First parse the header line with different tools to determine the column numbers.

```
wanted_columns=city,zip
{
  IFS= read header;
  cut_spec=$(printf %s "$header" |
             wanted_columns=",$wanted_columns," awk -v RS=, '
                 index(ENVIRON["wanted_columns"], ","$0",") {printf "%d,", NR}'
             );
  { printf %s\\n "$header"; cat; } | cut -d , -f "${cut_spec%,}";
}
```

If your CSV file is an actual CSV file with some quoted columns that can have embedded columns or newlines, use a proper CSV tool. For example, in [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import csv, sys
wanted_columns = set(sys.argv[1:])
reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
header = reader.next()
columns = [i for i in range(len(header)) if header[i] in wanted_columns]
writer=csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerow(sys.argv[1:])
for row in reader: writer.writerow([row[i] for i in columns])
```

(Pass the desired column names as arguments to the script.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have embedded `,` (meaning no `...,"foo,bar",...`) you can use `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f13,15
```

selects only columns 13 and 15 where columns are delimited by `,`. Why are columns 13 and 15 the right ones? I counted the commas with

```
head -n 1 data.csv | sed 's/zip,.*/,/' | tr -dc , | wc -c
```

Explanation: take the first line of input (`head`), find "zip" and replace it and the rest of the line with a comma (`sed`), then throw away everthing that is not a comma (`tr`) and count (`wc`). So "a,zip,b" is transformed to "a,,", to ",," to 2. "zip" is the second field.

Comment: The poster specified columns by name, I'm guessing they don't want to use column numbers.

Comment: Sure, but the poster didn't say explicitly what selection by number wouldn't be ok.

Comment: It is explicitly written *that I can specify the two names as arguments*, it is unreasonable to assume that someone is going to list all the ways he does *not* want the problem to be solved (assuming that exhaustively listing them is even possible), since he clearly indicated in which way he wanted it to be.